# string-float convertation to uint

Tags: solidity, string, error

**Hi** guys, i need **help**!

Trying to make a func that converts string-presented float with 2 dec to uint * 00

etc. if _s = "970452.22" result must be "97045222"

but i do something wrong (when i try to execute it tells me "*gas limit exceed 3000000*")

```
contract testfunction {

    string public converted;

    function stringFloatToUnsigned(string _s) payable {
        bytes memory _new_s;
        uint k = 0;

        for (uint i = 0; i < bytes(_s).length; i++) {
            if (bytes(_s)[i] == '.') { continue; }

            _new_s[k] = bytes(_s)[i];
            k++;
        }

        converted = string(_new_s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the `_new_s` bytes array. Eg something like

```
uint stringLength = bytes(_s).length;
bytes memory _new_s = new bytes(stringLength);
```

Then it seems to work for me.